# Shorthand for calling Concurrency within Combine sink?

Tags: swift, combine, swift-concurrency

I'm subscribing to Combine publishers, but frequently calling Concurrent tasks within the `.sink`. Is there a more convenient way to do this?

```swift
import _Concurrency
import Combine
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

struct MyService {
    private static let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

    init() {
        Task {
            try? await Task.sleep(until: .now + .seconds(2), clock: .suspending)
            Self.subject.send("Publisher: " + Date.now.formatted())
        }
    }

    func publisher() -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        Self.subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

class MyClass {
    let service: MyService
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        service = MyService()
        subscribe()
    }

    func subscribe() {
        // HERE ===>
        cancellable = service.publisher()
            .sink { value in Task { [weak self] in await self?.doThings(value: value) } }
    }

    func doThings(value: String) async {
        print(value)
        try? await Task.sleep(until: .now + .seconds(2), clock: .suspending)
        print("Things done!")
    }
}


let test = MyClass()


PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

What I'd like to do is seamlessly call Concurrency tasks in the `.sink` something like:

```swift
// From:
service.publisher()
    .sink { value in Task { [weak self] in await self?.doThings(value: value) }

// To:
service.publisher()
    .sink { [weak self] value in await self?.doThings(value: value) }
```

Comment: Just write an extension yourself? Surely you know how to do that?

Comment: I only found how to provide an async `map` using this as a guideline: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/calling-async-functions-within-a-combine-pipeline/. But extending the `sink` function wasn't straight forward as I hoped and couldn't overcome the generics or which part to extend.

Comment: Also hoping I missed a native API to do this? I thought there may be better native integration between Combine and Concurrency but couldn't find a good reference for bridging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an extension like this:

```
extension Publisher where Failure == Never {
    func sinkAsync(receiveValue: @escaping ((Self.Output) async throws -> Void)) -> AnyCancellable {
        sink { value in
            Task {
                try await receiveValue(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the closure it takes is `async throws`, which is the same as what the closure of `Task.init` has.

The "native" way of doing this, I think, would be to convert the publisher to an async sequence.

```
Task {
    for await value in service.publisher().values {
        await self.doThings(value: value)
    }
}
```

Note that by doing this, you don't need to manage the cancellable!